# getting the id of countries returns Expression 'mid = s.id' is non-assignable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function that returns a scope called **mid** to hold the id of countries to be assigned to populate states select box. Here is the function and scope initialized

```
$scope.logId = function() {
        $scope.mid = 1;
        console.log($scope.mid);
        return ($scope.mid);
    };
```

I have a loop of countries that returns the id during the loop. On trying to assign the id of the country in select option to **$scope mid** to change the initial **$scope.mid** of the function **$scope.logId** so that when I call the get states function it will receive the current id of the function **$scope.logId** I get this error

```
Expression 'mid = s.id' is non-assignable. Element: <option ng-repeat="s in countries" ng-model="mid = s.id" value="{{s.name}}" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope">
```

Here is the loop of the country where I am making the loop and assignment

```
<option ng-repeat="s in countries" ng-model="mid = s.id" value="{{s.name}}">{{s.name}}</option>
```

**EDITTED TO SHOW COMPLETE CODES**

```
<select ng-click="getCountries()" formcontrol name="country" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" required>



        <option ng-repeat="s in countries" ng-click="mid = s.id" value="{{s.name}}">{{s.name}}</option>

        </select>


    </div>

    <div ng-class = "{'has-error':frmValidation.state.$invalid && !frmValidation.state.$pristine}" class="field required">
      <label>State</label>
      <select ng-click="getStates(mid)" ng-model="reg.state" formcontrol name="state" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" required >

        <option ng-repeat="s in states" value="{{s.name}}">{{s.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Please assist to get the value of the **select option id** to be assigned to **scope mid** and received from **logId** function, so that whenever **ng-click is called on logId** it returns the current id of the selected country

Comment: you cannot use assignent operators for `ng-model`, you should use `ng-model="mid"`

Comment: how do I assign values to it and passed to the function logId in the html

Comment: what value you want to assign, please add some controller code?

Comment: this >>> ng-click="mid = s.id" during option select tag. But the challenge is I cannot get mid back in the function logId after option select

Comment: you should call `getCountries` from the controller, first

Comment: yes... check editted to show complete codes to go through and get modifications on what I have currently

Comment: have you implemented below answer? any issue you are facing?

Comment: yes I have.... I cannot get the id of country dynamically to logId() function when ever option is selected and the answer has hard coded values. I am not hard coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this code:

**I also implemented a `mock API call for countries`  in my `DEMO` please check**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-change="logId()" name="country"  ng-model="mid" required>
        <option ng-repeat="c in countries" value="{{c.name}}">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>


</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   
    
    $scope.getCountries = function(){
     $http.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
        $scope.countries = response.data;
    });
    }
    
    $scope.getCountries();
    


    $scope.logId = function() {
        
        alert($scope.mid);
        
    };
});

</script>

    <p>Please select a country and logId() will be called.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/pA8hLBylptioAsVJkmHY?p=preview)

Comment: @rocket, I implemented a mock API call in my `DEMO` please check

Comment: these seems to be more tailored but my api drop down is not pulling anymore

Comment: that `data` is more so it takes time to fill data into dropdown

Comment: when my page loads I get an error of bad request after implementing

Comment: you implemented the same api?

Comment: I followed what you did. Please can you move this to chat... please

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171829/getting-the-id-of-countries-returns-expression-mid-s-id-is-non-assignable

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of html and controller.
Check working sample [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FROUYJQEEJT1)

```
<select ng-change="getStates()" formcontrol name="country"  ng-model="cid" required>
        <option ng-repeat="c in countries" value="{{c.id}}">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>

<select formcontrol name="state"  ng-model="sid" required>
        <option ng-repeat="s in states" value="{{s.id}}">{{s.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Controller code

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cid = "1";
    $scope.countries = [
        {id : "1", name : "Country 1"},
        {id : "2", name : "Country 2"},
        {id : "3", name : "Country 3"}
    ];


    $scope.getStates = function() {
      console.log($scope.cid);
      someApiCall($scope.cid, function() {
            $scope.states = resultFromAPI;
       }) 
       /* $scope.states = [
          {id : "11", name : "State 1"},
          {id : "12", name : "State 2"},
          {id : "13", name : "State 3"}
      ];*/
    }
});
```

Comment: I think your implementation is wrong. Please try implementing like this https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_select.asp

Comment: I just hardcoded countries and states for demo. You can just as well call apis and update the list accordingly

Comment: I cannot iniitiate a chat with you. I see no link to do such a thing here. What exactly do you want ? I didnt get the meaning of your last message !

Comment: The id of the current selected country is in model 'cid' . You can access it like '$scope.cid'

Comment: should I show api codes so that you tweak it to your hard coded answer. I have tried but could not find a way out

Comment: Ok go ahead . but i am not sure what you want. Still will try